# How can I get image path from Firebase, get image from firebase storage, and show it?

Tags: image, download, show, angularfire2

I'm trying to;

1. get image path from firebase database
2. get image from firebase storage
3. show this image

I use Angular2/Angularfire2

Here is my current code;

```
 this.products = af.database.list('products/')
    this.products.subscribe((data: any) => {
        data.forEach(item => {
          firebase.storage().ref().child('products/' + item.img)
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(url => {
              item.image = url;
            });
        })
      }
    )
```

Here is my template;

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of products |async" text-center
      [ngStyle]="item.image ? {'background': 'url(' + (item?.image) + ')'} : {}">
```

I'm able to get path, and get download url.

However I'm not able to show it.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished temporary solution by adding extra array, and showing it. Any solutions still welcome.

```
this.productss = []

this.products = af.database.list('/products')
this.products.subscribe((data: any) => {
    data.forEach(item => {
      firebase.storage().ref().child('products/' + item.img)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
          item.image = url;
          this.productss.push(item)
        });
    })
  }
)
```